# Enter an "Any" value in a drop down from a query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I run a query to create a drop down.

```
$sql_course = "SELECT * FROM hc_course";
$result_course = mysql_query($sql_course);

echo "<select name='course_num'>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_course)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['course_num'] . "'>" . $row['course_name'] . "</option>";
   }
echo "</select>";
```

This produces the list with all the names correctly.

However, I would like to inject an "any" entry that would then turn the next query based off of this from a `'course_num'` into a `*`.

Comment: Did any of the below answers help?

Comment: @jszobody Yes, yours did. Looking at it after the fact makes so much sense. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
echo "<select name='course_num'>";
echo "<option value='*'>Any</option>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_course)) {
    ....
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "<select name='course_num'>";
echo "<option value='*'>Any</option>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_course)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['course_num'] . "'>" . $row['course_name'] . "</option>";
   }

echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You should **never trust user input** so you would need to add some form of PHP sanitisation to process the request.

Initial code:

```
$sql_course = "SELECT * FROM hc_course";
$result_course = mysql_query($sql_course);

echo "<select name='course_num'>";
echo "<option value="">Any</option>"; // New code for all courses
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_course)) {
    echo "<option value='" . htmlspecialchars($row['course_num']) . "'>" . htmlspecialchars($row['course_name']) . " </option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

And the code on the page handling this request should work something like this:

```
if (empty($_POST["course_num"]))
{
    // Run SQL to select all courses
}
else
{
    // Sanitise the $_POST["course_num"]
    // Run SQL to select a specific course item
}
```

Comment: Good point, but that also applies to the html output so you would use `htmlspecialchars($row['course_num'])`, etc. Not directly user input, but it needs encoding just the same.

Comment: At this point I am just trying to learn basic logic for all of this. I am going to start to adopt better practices and start to move towards MySQLi or PDO statements, but for now, I am so new to all this I am happy just to get past `echo "Hi World";`